# seahorse: How do I view the Login Keyring?

Tags: gnome, login, password, seahorse

I want to view the Passwords stored in the Login Keyring. Apparently I should look in **Seahorse > View By Keyring** and select **Login** under **Passwords**. But as far I can see, there is no **Login** keyring in Seahorse. See image below.

[image: No Login Keyring]

However, there appears to be a **Login** keyring stored in `~/.local/share/keyrings`, see image below.

[image: Shell]

Is this a bug I should be reporting or am I missing something here?

Comment: I've got the same issue with Ubuntu 18.10. Did you find a solution and/or did you already report a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it did the trick for me:

1. Open the Passwords & Keys application
2. Go to the "View" menu
3. Click on the "Show All" option at the bottom

For Ubuntu 20.04 and later this would be the three vertical dots menu button at the top right.

[image]

If this does not work, try the solution provided at https://askubuntu.com/a/936982/32968. I tried that first but it did not change anything for me.

Comment: 20.04 doesn't appear to have a "View" menu item

Comment: @AntonOfTheWoods they just removed the text and gave it a three vertical dots icon at the top right.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turned out I was starting seahorse as root, so the list was empty since root doesn't have any keyring set up usually.